# expecting bitrate: 352 kb/s WAV but getting bitrate 353 kb/s

Tags: ffmpeg, wav

Using `ffprobe` to get the converted wav properties, I get

```
Input #0, wav, from '01.wav':
  Metadata:
    title           : 1
    album           : 1
    track           : 1
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.28, bitrate: 353 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
```

The files were converted using the command (windows):

```
FOR /R wav_22k_353 %%F in (*.wav) do C:\ffmpeg-4.1-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg -i %%F -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 -b:a 352k wav_22k\%%~nF.wav
```

Getting 353 instead of 352. Is there any way to solve the issue?

**EDIT**

The original files info, for example:

```
Input #0, wav, from '01.wav':
  Metadata:
    title           : 1
    album           : 1
    track           : 1
  Duration: 00:00:02.28, bitrate: 354 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
```

Comment: 22050*16=352800. Depends on how you round it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I need 352 exactly, because 352800 ~ 353k

Comment: Then change the sample rate so that it is exactly 352k? That would be 22kHz

Comment: Sample rate cannot be changed because it is fixed by the used algorithm.

Comment: Then you can’t have the bitrate you want

Comment: I have some other wav files downloaded that shows: `Input #0, wav, from '0001.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:09.66, bitrate: 352 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s` so how?

Comment: The original file's format duration is 35**4** kb/s.

Comment: You’ll have to ask the devs or read the source on how they calculate. It doesn’t change the fact that bitrate is samplerate times bits per sample. If you can’t change any of them then you can’t have what you want.